# How to parse Http POST response body in Java

Tags: java, forms, parsing, post

A html form post is received for standard JDK lib and fetched with HttpExchange and passed to

```
private String getBodyString(HttpExchange he){
    String ret=null;
    InputStream is = he.getRequestBody();
    URLDecoder dc = new URLDecoder();
        
    try {    
        ret = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)).readLine();
        ret = dc.decode(ret, StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name());
    }catch (NullPointerException ex){
        Logger.getLogger(RequestBodyParser.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(RequestBodyParser.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    return ret;
}
```

returns:

```
mytxt1=huhu&mytxt2=haha&btnOk=1
```

Where mytxt1 and mytxt2 are inputs. Now I want to parse key (name) and values (text) from it.

This is the good example. I could easly do some String split with "&" and devide key and value with "=". But there are also the bad:

```
mytxt1=huhu & haha &mytxt2=haha&btnOk=1
```

...and the ugly:

```
mytxt1=Lorem &mytxt2=Ugly Injection&mytxt2=haha&btnOk=1
```

And I haven't jet started to talk about "select multiple". Is there any best practice to parse form entries in a safe manner with included JDK libs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, [URLDecoder.decode is a static method](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/net/URLDecoder.html#decode(java.lang.String,java.lang.String)).  Do not create an instance of URLDecoder when calling it.  (In fact, [that constructor is now deprecated.](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/net/URLDecoder.html#%3Cinit%3E()))

Second, do not catch NullPointerException.  NullPointerException indicates that the programmer made a mistake.  If a NullPointerException occurs, the programmer needs to fix the mistake, not hide it.

Third, you should not pass the entire query to a single URLDecoder.decode call.  When you do that, you lose the ability to distinguish between `&` and `=` characters that actually denote query parameter names and values, and `&` and `=` characters which were present in the actual names or values.

For instance, if I start with this query:

```
candy=M%26Ms&fruit=pineapple
```

And then I pass the entire query to URLDecoder.decode, I end up with this:

```
candy=M&Ms&fruit=pineapple
```

Now the program has no way to know that there were only two parameters, `candy` and `fruit`.  It now appears that there are three:  `candy`, `Ms` (with no corresponding value), and `fruit`.

The solution to this is to first split the parameters, then split key/value pairs, then decode each key and value.

```
private Map<String, List<String>> getBodyString(HttpExchange he) {
    Map<String, List<String>> parameters = new LinkedHashMap<>();

    String query;
    try (InputStream body = he.getRequestBody()) {
        query = new String(body.readAllBytes(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }

    String[] keyValuePairs = query.split("&");
    for (String keyValuePair : keyValuePairs) {
        String[] keyAndValue = keyValuePair.split("=", 2);

        String key = keyAndValue[0];
        String value = keyAndValue.length > 1 ? keyAndValue[1] : "";

        key = URLDecoder.decode(key, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        value = URLDecoder.decode(value, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

        parameters.computeIfAbsent(key, k -> new ArrayList<>()).add(value);
    }

    return parameters;
}
```

There currently is no method in Java SE for parsing query parameters (even though many have requested it).